# How to protect email addresses after domain name expires?

Tags: email, domain-name, impersonation

I'm thinking of creating a website for a friend. This includes registering a domain name and setting up a couple email addresses (myfriend@myfriend.com, etc.)

If the friend doesn't maintain the domain registration, and the domain falls into the hands of a nefarious actor, how can I protect my friends email addresses?

If I'm not mistaken, it is a common tactic to register a defunct domain name and impersonate the associated email addresses.

What can be done to avoid this?

Comment: Some legislations may be more suitable than others to get ones name back (especially so if it matches a registered trademark), and some TLDs are strictly operated such that name resolution will stop working well before redemption becomes difficult (meaning pending delete is more noticeable). Consider picking something in the intersection of these.

Comment: What if the person doesn't want the website (and consequently the domain name) anymore? Is it true that once a domain name is registered, it must be registered FOREVER otherwise ANY email associated with the domain could be compromised in the event of domain forfeiture?

Comment: You cannot protect users from themselves.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to say that the answer is to make sure that your friend understands the importance of maintaining a domain name and the associated emails.  And if this is "just for fun," then maybe it's not a good idea.

At the least, it would be wise to not use the mail address for anything important.  And since it's silly to own a custom domain name just for junk mail...I point back to my original recommendation.

The other option is to have the domain name, but don't use it for email.  Just for a website or something.

Or, just pay more and own the domain for a long enough time that it doesn't matter.  Buy it for 100 years or something.  "Set it and forget it."

Comment: You can only renew the domain up to 9 years, as the expiry date can't be more than 10 years in the future. For some TLDs it's even lower.

Answer (score 2):

No way. The only way to protect email addresses inside a domain is to maintain that domain registered and controlled. If you want anything regarding that domain, you have to own it, not letting to to expire.